# Start song at specific second of it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-player

I have background music that it is a 6 minute loop. The song has 4 parts and it can start playing in any of those parts.

How can I start playing a song in a specific part of it in Unity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try by setting the `time` property of your `AudioSource`:

```
//Set the playback time to 3 seconds
audioSource.time = 3;

//Play the audio
audioSource.Play();
```

If you are audio is compressed, take into account what it is written in the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html):

> Be aware that: On a compressed audio track position does not necessary
>   reflect the actual time in the track Compressed audio is represented
>   as a set of so-called packets. The length of a packet depends on the
>   compression settings and can quite often be 2-3 seconds per packet

In this case, you may want to use the property `timeSamples` instead:

```
// Seek 1 sample forward (about 2-3 seconds)
audioSource.timeSamples = 1;

//Play the audio
audioSource.Play();
```

You might also want to check the open source tool [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), to split your files into several sounds, and then you can just play the sound you need when you need it.

See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-timeSamples.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I didn't think that it meant the current second, I would have named it currentSecond or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look up for [FMOD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJRIowt_6PE).

Otherwise, you need to set [AudioSource.Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html) (playback position in seconds) with the desired time.